# Help me initialize a containers.Map

Tags: matlab

M = containers.Map('KeyType', 'double')

instead of giving me a map that takes keys of type double, it gives me a map that his one key (the string 'KeyType') with value 'double'

-_-
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

You also have to specify the value type; So you need to write `M = containers.Map('KeyType', 'double', 'ValueType', whatever)`.

Answer (score 1):

Just a note: the reason that the `containers.Map()` constructor requires both to be specified is that otherwise there would be ambiguity with the `containers.Map(keys,values)` constructor.

Answer (score 0):

```
>> f=containers.Map('KeyType','double','ValueType','char')
f = 
  Map with properties:
        Count: 0
      KeyType: double
    ValueType: char
>> f(3)='Hello'
f = 
  Map with properties:
        Count: 1
      KeyType: double
    ValueType: charf=containers.Map('KeyType','char','ValueType','double')
```

Note that you can also initialize it like:

```
f=containers.Map({3,4},{'a','foo'})
f = 
  Map with properties:
        Count: 2
      KeyType: double
    ValueType: char
```